# JavaFX Application proportions are not right

Tags: java, javafx, center

I am trying to set my applications center in the middle of the screen, and I apparently figured out myself the common solution proposed on other threads here at StackOverFlow, although you can clearly see that the application should be further to the left.

[image: Proportions]

The screen I am using now is a 1920x1080, but the same thing used to happen on the 1366x766 screen.

```
Rectangle2D p = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
double w = p.getWidth() / 1.5;
double h = p.getHeight() / 1.5;
stage.setWidth(w);
stage.setHeight(h);
stage.setX(p.getWidth()/2 - stage.getWidth()/2);
stage.setY(p.getHeight()/2 - stage.getHeight()/2);
```

The stage proportions are (in my case) 1280x720
Is there any reason why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Ok, I figured out that it works pretty well (from someones comment) and that the issue is the windows application bar that I positioned on the left, whilst when it is on the original position, the application is central.

Comment: I just tried your code. I had no problems.

Comment: Yet you can see thai it is pretty wrong from the picture

Comment: If you found the code on another post and it's working for everyone but you, you could be using a Java version with a bug or you could be doing something somewhere else that's causing your problem.

Comment: All functioning, apparently Java dislikes Windows toolbar set on left/right verticals.

Comment: cool that you found the reason - you might consider answering your own question :)